# Pi Boot Crash with Disabled Keyboard

Tags: retropie

been tinkering for a few days on a retrogaming system on pi 3 - I've run into an issue where the pi has failed to boot and the keyboard is dead so I can't access anything from the command line - any ideas?[image]

I think I will just have to start again but please let me know if there is an alt option. The install is retropie straight install without noobs.

Answer (score 1):

Sorted it by accessing via Putty and deleting two folders from retropie that had recently had 100s of roms added plus scraped - first time using putty so useful learning curve